# Athena describe or show table as create: "Unsupported ddl with 2 catalogs"

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena, presto

My AWS Athena has two catalogs that it can query from, `catalog1` and `catalog2`. I need to be able to specify the catalog when running `select` statements, but also `describe` and `show create table` statements. I'm trying running any of the following statements, but I get an error with every one:

```
show create table "catalog1"."my_schema"."my_table"
show create table `catalog1`.`my_schema`.`my_table`
show create table `catalog1.my_schema.my_table`
show create table `catalog1.my_schema`.`my_table`
```

Similarly,

```
describe "catalog1"."my_schema"."my_table"
describe `catalog1`.`my_schema`.`my_table`
describe `catalog1.my_schema.my_table`
describe `catalog1.my_schema`.`my_table`
```

**Problem**

With any of the above queries, I receive the error `Unsupported ddl with 2 catalogs` or `Invalid table name` if they don't like my groupings within back ticks.

**Context**

I *can* just switch the `Data Source` dropdown to the appropriate catalog, and then run without the catalog in the query (e.g. `describe my_schema. my_table`), but I want a way to use the fully qualified string.